# Chain of objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object;

```
class MyObject
{
   double Timestamp;
   string Originalname;
   string Renamedname;
}
```

I have an array of MyObject

> 1538148190,"C:\test\jeff.txt","jeffmodified.txt"
>   1538148200,"C:\test\jeffmodified.txt","jeffmodified2.txt"
>   1538148289,"C:\test\jeffmodified2.txt","jeffmodified3.txt"
>   1538149002,"C:\test\thing.txt","something.txt"

I am trying to create a correlation of the data to present the idea that jeff.txt was renamed to jeffmodified.tx and then to jeff.modified2.txt and jeffmodified3.txt.  The timestamp (unix format) shows me that jeff.txt was the original file name.

Can this be done in linq?  This is working with objects in memory only - not a database and the max number of objects would generally be 200 objects.

Comment: So you want this done in one query on the db using link to sql or EF?

Comment: I cant really think of a way to do this reliably on a db without recursion, or cursor based approach, neither of which seemingly can be done in Linq... or maybe CLR stored procedure might be another approach

Comment: Do you *need* this to run on the db?  If so, you should add some sort of DB tag to the question, like EntityFramework, or SqlServer.  Right now it is just tagged for LINQ, which doesn't involve the database.

Comment: When you are finished, what do you want as a result? Do you want items sorted properly, items grouped into "modification chains), something else? Do you want the times in the output...?

Comment: When done the answer I need is: what is the original file name?

Comment: This is NOT to be done on a database.  Just an array of MyObjects

Comment: *"When done the answer I need is: what is the original file name?"*. That is a single result from the collection, which implies that there would need to be some kind of filtering going on. Are you supplying a filename and a timestamp as a starting point, to return the original filename? (P.S. This really isn't clear from the question, you should [edit] it to make it clear what you want.)

Comment: If you can modify the class Object, add an `ID` field, just a number (int) will do. Each subsequent modification of the original file will have the same `ID`. This way you can `OrderBy(obj => obj.TimeStamp)` and `GroupBy(obj => obj.ID)`. Much easier to handle and not error prone. Use public properties instead of (private) instance fields.

Comment: @Jeff, more detail pls. Do we assume that: (as @Peeyush has) files are always renamed in the same directory; (as the sample data implies) the data contains a rename audit for multiple files; once a file has been renamed, another can be renamed back into its place?  (`file1.txt`->`file2.txt`, `file0.txt`->`file1.txt`). Your comment (_the answer I need is: ..._) implies a function `GetOriginalName(currentFile, renameAudit)`, but the question implies something else. I assume you actually want a data structure at the end. If you can define that for us, you may even answer your own question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using linq this cannot be done in a one or two liner (if that is what you meant by can this be done in linq. But due to linq the solution does become easier then what it would have been without linq.

The important assumptions that I have made in the solution below is that the timestamp will increase with each file name change. Solution is explained in the comments provided.

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // setting up test data, can be removed from actual solution where objects can be populated as required
            List<MyObject> objects = new List<MyObject>();
            objects = GetData(); 
            int i = 0;
            int key = 0;
            List<WrapMyObject> wObjs = new List<WrapMyObject>();
            Dictionary<int, string> origDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            Dictionary<int, string> searchDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();


            // adding the directory path to the renamed filename as well, since same filename can be there for different filepath
            Func<string, string> GetFilePath = (path) => path.Substring(0, path.LastIndexOf('\\'));
            objects.ForEach(x=>x.Renamedname = GetFilePath(x.Originalname) + "\\" + x.Renamedname);

            //sort the whole list by timestamp, this should ensure that we begin always with the orignal file and always get subsequent changed filename in the list
            //the algorithm relies on the fact that the renamed name should be the next orignal name for that file change in the sorted list 
            //if current item's orignal name is not in search dictory then we are seeing this file path first time, add to orignal dictionary with key, add the renamed name in search dictionary with same key
            //else add add the search path found in searchDictionary back into origDictionary and update the searchDict with the new path value (current item renamed path)
            var sortedObjects = objects.OrderBy(o => o.Timestamp);
            foreach (var item in objects)
            {              
                if (searchDictionary.ContainsValue(item.Originalname))
                    {                    
                        key = searchDictionary.Where(x => x.Value == item.Originalname).First().Key;
                        origDictionary[key] = origDictionary[key] + "!" + searchDictionary[key];
                        searchDictionary[key] = item.Renamedname;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        origDictionary.Add(i, item.Originalname);
                        searchDictionary.Add(i, item.Renamedname);
                    }
                i++;
            }            
            //iterated the whole list of objects....which means the final node would be remaining in the search dictionary, add them back to origDictionary to complete the modified path
            searchDictionary.ToList().ForEach(x => origDictionary[x.Key] = origDictionary[x.Key] + "!" + searchDictionary[x.Key]);

            //at this point orgnalDict has the list of all names that each file was modified with.
        }
```